# Hide Line Chart Limit Lines. Swift 2

Tags: swift, linechart, ios-charts

I am using the Charts frameworks (danielgindi/Charts).

I have a segment showing 1,2 & 3. Depending on the choice the line graph should display that amount of lines within a line chart. 
I have a switch statement, that depending on the number provided within the segment that displays that amount of lines. E.g. within case1, 1 line is shown, case 2, 2 lines are shown etc.. & this works as expected.

When I try to add limit lines within this switch statement and switch from a higher case to a lower e.g. 3 to 2, the 3rd line doesn't disappear & line 1 and 2 seem to have duplications.

Is there anyway of hiding the limit lines within the switch statement?

I have the following code:

```
 func setChart(xValues: [String], valuesLineChart: [[Double]], limitLines: [Double]) {
    chartView.descriptionText = ""
    chartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

    print("valuesLineChart has \(valuesLineChart.count) lines")

    var dataSets : [LineChartDataSet] = [LineChartDataSet]()

    switch valuesLineChart.count {

    case 1 : print("1 within switch")

    var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for i in 0..<xValues.count {
        yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(value: valuesLineChart[0][i], xIndex: i))
    }

    let set1 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals1, label: nil)
    dataSets.append(set1)

    //limit lines
    let limitSet1 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[0], label: "switch1, limit1")
    chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet1)

    case 2 :print("2 within switch")

    var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for i in 0..<xValues.count {
        yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(value: valuesLineChart[0][i], xIndex: i))
    }

    var yVals2 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for i in 0..<xValues.count {
        yVals2.append(ChartDataEntry(value: valuesLineChart[1][i], xIndex: i))
    }

    let set1 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals1, label: nil)
    let set2 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals2, label: nil)

    dataSets.append(set1)
    dataSets.append(set2)

    //limit lines
    let limitSet1 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[0], label: "")
    let limitSet2 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[1], label: "")

    chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet1)
    chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet2)


    case 3 :print("3 within switch")

    var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for i in 0..<xValues.count {
        yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(value: valuesLineChart[0][i], xIndex: i))
    }

    var yVals2 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for i in 0..<xValues.count {
        yVals2.append(ChartDataEntry(value: valuesLineChart[1][i], xIndex: i))
    }

    var yVals3 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for i in 0..<xValues.count {
        yVals3.append(ChartDataEntry(value: valuesLineChart[2][i], xIndex: i))
    }

    let set1 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals1, label: nil)
    let set2 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals2, label: nil)
    let set3 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals3, label: nil)

    dataSets.append(set1)
    dataSets.append(set2)
    dataSets.append(set3)

    //limit lines
    let limitSet1 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[0], label: "")
    let limitSet2 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[1], label: "")
    let limitSet3 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[2], label: "")

    chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet1)
    chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet2)
    chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet3)
    }

    let data: CombinedChartData = CombinedChartData(xVals: xValues)
    data.lineData = LineChartData(xVals: xValues, dataSets: dataSets)
    chartView.data = data
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. When the segment was selecting a different number, i was recalling the setChart function causing duplications of limitLines.

To solve this problem i removed the limit lines prior to recalling the setChart function;

```
var limitSet1 : ChartLimitLine?
var limitSet2 : ChartLimitLine?
var limitSet3 : ChartLimitLine?
var limitLineArray : [Double]

func removeLimitLines {
    switch (limitLineArray.count) {
            case 1: print("there was 1 limit line, need to remove this from chart view")
            chartView.rightAxis.removeLimitLine(limitSet1!)
            case 2: print("there was 2 limit line, need to remove this from chart view")
            chartView.rightAxis.removeLimitLine(limitSet1!)
            chartView.rightAxis.removeLimitLine(limitSet2!)
            case 3: print("there was 3 limit line, need to remove this from chart view")
            chartView.rightAxis.removeLimitLine(limitSet1!)
            chartView.rightAxis.removeLimitLine(limitSet2!)
            chartView.rightAxis.removeLimitLine(limitSet3!)
    }
}

func setChart(xValues: [String], valuesLineChart: [[Double]], limitLines: [Double]) {
chartView.descriptionText = ""
chartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

print("valuesLineChart has \(valuesLineChart.count) lines")

var dataSets : [LineChartDataSet] = [LineChartDataSet]()

switch valuesLineChart.count {

case 1 : print("1 within switch")

var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<xValues.count {
    yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(value: valuesLineChart[0][i], xIndex: i))
}

let set1 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals1, label: nil)
dataSets.append(set1)

//limit lines
limitSet1 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[0], label: "switch1, limit1")
chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet1)

case 2 :print("2 within switch")

var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<xValues.count {
    yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(value: valuesLineChart[0][i], xIndex: i))
}

var yVals2 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<xValues.count {
    yVals2.append(ChartDataEntry(value: valuesLineChart[1][i], xIndex: i))
}

let set1 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals1, label: nil)
let set2 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals2, label: nil)

dataSets.append(set1)
dataSets.append(set2)

//limit lines
limitSet1 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[0], label: "")
limitSet2 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[1], label: "")

chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet1)
chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet2)


case 3 :print("3 within switch")

var yVals1 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<xValues.count {
    yVals1.append(ChartDataEntry(value: valuesLineChart[0][i], xIndex: i))
}

var yVals2 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<xValues.count {
    yVals2.append(ChartDataEntry(value: valuesLineChart[1][i], xIndex: i))
}

var yVals3 : [ChartDataEntry] = [ChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<xValues.count {
    yVals3.append(ChartDataEntry(value: valuesLineChart[2][i], xIndex: i))
}

let set1 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals1, label: nil)
let set2 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals2, label: nil)
let set3 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals3, label: nil)

dataSets.append(set1)
dataSets.append(set2)
dataSets.append(set3)

//limit lines
limitSet1 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[0], label: "")
limitSet2 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[1], label: "")
limitSet3 = ChartLimitLine(limit: limitLines[2], label: "")

chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet1)
chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet2)
chartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(limitSet3)
}

let data: CombinedChartData = CombinedChartData(xVals: xValues)
data.lineData = LineChartData(xVals: xValues, dataSets: dataSets)
chartView.data = data
}
```

Now, I call the removeLimitLines before the setChart function and it works as expected.

EDIT:

you can also just simply call:

```
chartView.leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines()
```